# Web3.js + ganache local development: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check, CORS error

Tags: web3js, ganache

I am fairly new to DAPP and I am trying to follow an online guide building my first smart contract. Here's the source code:

**Election.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Election {

    string public candidateName;

    constructor (string _candidateName) public {
        candidateName = _candidateName;
    }

    function setCandidate (string _name) public {
        candidateName = _name;
    }

}
```

I've deployed to to my local Ganache (latest version on windows 10) and tried to interact with it using the **Web3.js** from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.min.js).

Here's my JavaScript code for my client side:

```
// Initialise web3
if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
}

// Set account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

// Set contract abi
var contractAbi = [ ... my aib here ... ];

// Set contract address
var contractAddress = "my-contract-address-here";

// Load the contract
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);

// Display current candidate name
contract.candidateName(function(err, candidateName) {
  if (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
  } else {
    $("#canidateName").val(candidateName);
  }
});

// Handle candidate name update
$("#updateCandidate").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  contract.setCandidate($("#canidateName").val());
});
```

When I run my app in the browser, I am getting the following error:

> web3.min.js:1 Failed to load http://localhost:7545/: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
>   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.
>
> Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node
>   http://localhost:7545.
>       at Object.InvalidConnection (web3.min.js:1)
>       at t.send (web3.min.js:1)
>       at n.send (web3.min.js:1)
>       at l.accounts (web3.min.js:1)
>       at script.js:9 InvalidConnection @ web3.min.js:1 t.send @ web3.min.js:1 n.send @ web3.min.js:1 (anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
>   (anonymous) @ script.js:9

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've worked out what the problem is.

Since my "client" doesn't technically need a webserver, I ran my html app directly from my desktop, i.e. it was executing from this url in chrome:

file:///C:/Users/Latheesan/Desktop/Crypto%20Election/index.html

After I moved it into a local webserver (e.g. apache) and running it from this url:

http://localhost/Crypto%20Election/

It's now working, I am no longer getting CORS errors.